# Tensor operators and transformation of $O^s_{\ell}|j,m,\alpha\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, group-representations, representation-theory

In H. Georgi's *Lie Algebras in Particle Physics* one defines a tensor operator transforming under the spin-$s$ representation of $SU(2)$ as the set of operators $O^s_{\ell}$ (for $\ell=-s...s$) such that

$$[J_a,O^s_{\ell}] = O^s_m~[J_a^s]_{m\ell}, \tag{4.1}$$

where $J_a$ are the generators of $SU(2)$.

Next we want to consider how the product $O^s_{\ell}|j,m,\alpha\rangle$ transforms:

$$J_a O^s_{\ell}|j,m,\alpha\rangle = [J_a,O^s_{\ell}]|j,m,\alpha\rangle+O^s_{\ell} J_a\vert j,m,\alpha\rangle \\
 = O^s_{\ell'} \vert j,m,\alpha\rangle[J_a^s]_{\ell'\ell} +O^s_{\ell}\vert j,m',\alpha\rangle [J_a^j]_{m'm}. \tag{4.13} $$

Now here is where I don't follow. I think I know how he got the second term on the rhs. of eq. (4.13), namely inserting a complete set of states (summing over $m'$) we get (please correct me if I'm wrong!)

$$O^s_{\ell} J_a\vert j,m,\alpha\rangle = O^s_{\ell} |j,m',\alpha\rangle \langle j, m', \alpha|J_a\vert j,m,\alpha\rangle = O^s_{\ell} |j,m',\alpha\rangle [J_a^j]_{m'm}$$

**But for the first term I am not sure how that matrix element got on the right hand side of the ket?** Any explanation of how

$$[J_a,O^s_{\ell}]|j,m,\alpha\rangle$$

became

$$O^s_{\ell'} \vert j,m,\alpha\rangle[J_a^s]_{\ell'\ell}$$

is greatly appreciated.

What confuses me is that the same author claims that matrix representations act on kets from the right. He shows this by using ($D$ being a repr and $g$ group element)

$$ D(g)|j\rangle = \sum_k |k\rangle\langle k| D(g)|j\rangle = \sum_k |k\rangle [D(g)]_{kj}, \tag{1.98}$$

and then emphasized this in bold letters by stating: (p. 24)

> *One could use a different symbol to represent the operators and the matrices [...] the important point is that the way this acts on the state, $|j\rangle$ is by matrix multiplication **on the right**.*

Answer (score 1):

Let us put an hat on operators, which acts non-trivially on kets:

$$ [\hat{J}_a,\hat{O}^s_{\ell}] ~=~ \hat{O}^s_m~[J_a^s]_{m\ell}, \tag{4.1}$$

The matrix element

$$[J_a^s]_{\ell^{\prime}\ell}~\in~\mathbb{C}$$

is just a complex number and hence commutes with a ket. Hence

$$[\hat{J}_a,\hat{O}^s_{\ell}]|j,m,\alpha\rangle
~\stackrel{(4.1)}{=}~ \hat{O}^s_{\ell'}~[J_a^s]_{\ell'\ell}|j,m,\alpha\rangle
~=~\hat{O}^s_{\ell'} \vert j,m,\alpha\rangle[J_a^s]_{\ell'\ell}.$$

References:

1. H. Georgi, *Lie Algebras in Particle Physics,* 2nd edition, 1999.